# How to Know if I'm accessing html page from web or mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, html

Is there any way I can find out wether I am accessing an html page from a Mobile (Smartphone, Tablets) device or my Laptop ? I have a local html page and I need a javascript function to do different stuff if the page is being viewed on a mobile device or on a desktop.

Comment: What do you need to do differently, and why does the device matter? Does the device really matter? Or is it the location that matters? Or the screen size? Or the lack of keyboard? Or addition of a touch screen? It's usually better to address what really matters rather then using some arbitrary "mobile" or "desktop" measure.

Comment: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ provides for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a full client solution you can check the client [`user agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent) to check if the browser is mobile or not and do your stuff.

To check it you can get a fully working regexp here: [DetectMobileBrowsers.com](http://DetectMobileBrowsers.com)

JS Regexp for mobile detection from the site:

> (function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge
>   |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm(
>   os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows
>   (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a
>   wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r
>   |s
>   )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw-(n|u)|c55/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(-|*)|g1
>   u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-(m|p|t)|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(
>   i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c(-|
>   |*|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(
>   |-|/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(
>   |/)|klon|kpt |kwc-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(
>   g|/(k|l|u)|50|54|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(-|
>   |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v
>   )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk/|se(c(-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie(-|m)|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v
>   )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel(i|m)|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(-|
>   )|webc|whit|wi(g
>   |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas-|your|zeto|zte-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');

Comment: Ive tried that website on my tablet (Asus Transformer tf101) and it didnt recognize as a mobile browser...

Comment: But you don't have to open the website but get the provided script and use it, added the mobile detection in js.

Comment: Basically I have an html page on localhost and if I access it via laptop (locally) the url can be http://localhost:/blablabla  while when I access it via mobile i have to access  http://192.168/blablabla

Answer (score 2):

The two options available to you are

1. Using a server-side scripting language to parse the browsers user agent string and including different scripts/adding different classes based on the results
2. Use a combination of CSS media queries and Javascript sniffing to react to the device size/capabilities instead of the type of device

It sounds as though the second option is probably better suited to your needs